# VMware: Automatically change Arch Linux textmode resolution

Tags: linux, vmware, virtualization, arch-linux, fullscreen

I have installed the most basic Arch Linux only with command line interface as guest OS on Windows using VMware. The problem is when I maximize the Vmware window, the Arch Linux console does not adjust to the full screen. How to do this without installing X window?

I also want to make copy-paste work to and fro from windows without installing X. Is it possible?

Comment: a problem i had that you might be having is that vmware tools don't get loaded until after the screensize is determined. you could always just ssh in with putty...this solves both problems

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for VM-Ware tools tar installer.  Directions for installation are here: http://www.vmware.com/support/ws5/doc/ws_newguest_tools_linux.html

Basically, vmware tools gets you more resolutions supported.  It is possible to install it without X, but I haven't tested it on arch.  I had mixed results on debian derivatives.

edit:
a problem i had that you might be having is that vmware tools don't get loaded until after the screensize is determined. you could always just ssh in with putty...this solves both problems

Answer (score 0):

As far as I'm aware, there's no way to change a KMS framebuffer's resolution after booting.

Also, copy/paste won't work. There's really no such thing without a clipboard, now is there. ;)

If you want all the shiny VM integration features, you'll have to install Xorg.